# c# создание хэш таблиц с линейным пробированием

Tags: c#, хеширование

Только начинаю изучать c# и не могу понять создание хэш-таблиц. Вернее простым способом я создал, но нужно использовать линейное пробирование. Что это, понятно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Task
{

    static public void Main()
    {

        Hashtable my_hashtable1 = new Hashtable();

        
        my_hashtable1.Add("a", 23);
        my_hashtable1.Add("b", 13);
        my_hashtable1.Add("c", 346);


        
       
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Саму таблицу я создал. Но как добавить линейное пробирование, не понятно. Возможно, создать таблицу только с ключами, а потом к ключу добавлять значение. Но Add не дает добавить только ключ, требует оба значения.

Comment: линейное пробирование - это способ реализации хештаблицы. То есть вам надо видимо свою написать таблицу, а не использовать уже готовую.

Comment: Нужно видимо самому создать класс, реализующий хэштаблицу, а не использовать `Hashtable` или `HashSet<T>`. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Hashtable.cs